# Interval on which a circle is a function

Tags: functions, circles

The following equation represents a circle:
$(x-1)^2+(y-3)^2 =\frac{1}{4}.$

It is not a function (we can prove this using the vertical line test).

On what interval can it be defined as a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x-1)^2+(y-3)^2 =\frac{1}{4}.$ can be defined as two functions. Each one represents a semicircle

$ f:[\frac{1}{2}; \frac{3}{2}] \rightarrow [3; \frac{7}{2}] , y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} -(x-1)^2}+3$

and

$f:[\frac{1}{2}; \frac{3}{2}] \rightarrow [-3; \frac{-7}{2}]
 y=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} -(x-1)^2}+3$